# Docker: "manifest unknown" when not specifying image version in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I created an image called myrepo/myimage:0.0.1 and pushed it to my docker hub repo using the push command.

After that I tried running docker-compose up from the directory where my docker-compose.yml is located to bring that image up. However, if I don't specify the image version I get the following error: `ERROR: manifest for myrepo/myimage not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown`.

My docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
    version: '2'
services:
    postgres_globally_united:
        image: postgres
        ports:
            - "3460:5432"
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=agjAFk3!Rk2#!lapA@
        image: myrepo/myimage
        ports:
            - "7001:80"
```

I also tried doing it by defining the image like this in docker-compose.yml: myrepo/myimage:latest. However, I got the similar error.

How can I make Docker get the latest image. I see that for the postres image it works just fine...

Comment: That compose file is broken in several ways, version is indented incorrectly, and you've defined image and ports twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the specific tag of your image in the compose file or [tag the image](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/) as `latest` and push that.

```
docker tag myrepo/myimage:0.0.1 myrepo/myimage:latest
docker push myrepo/myimage:latest
```

`latest` is not automatically created for you, if you build/push with a specific tag. If you leave the tag off, then `latest` will be used as the default tag.

Also note that you can provide multiple tags when [building](http://myrepo/myimage:latest), which may be more convenient than building with one tag and tagging it again.

```
docker build --tag myrepo/myimage:latest --tag myrepo/myimage:0.0.1 .
```